# Рендеринг свойств checkbox'а vue.js

Tags: vue.js

Почему не рендерится свойство `value` чекбокса?

Хочу сделать так, чтобы в свойство `value=""` чекбокса, подставлялось свойство `name` итерируемого объекта. А оно не подставляется. Уже и v-bind'ом пробовал, и {{}}. Не хочет подставлять и всё! Рендерит так:
`<input type="checkbox" value="item.name">`

Может потому что в `name` встречается кириллица?

```html
<tr v-for="(item, index) in tags" :key="index">
    <td class="checkbox">
       <input type="checkbox" value="item.name" v-model="checkedNames">
    </td>           
    <td class="tag">{{item.name}}</td>           
</tr>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`:value` так пробовали?

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#test',
  data() {
    return {
      tags:[
        {name:"1"},
        {name:"2"},
      ]
    }
  },
  mounted(){
    console.log(
       Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]')).map(el =>
            el.value
       )
    );
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.4.2/vue.min.js"></script>
<table id='test'>
  <tr v-for="(item, index) in tags" :key="index">
      <td class="checkbox">
         <input type="checkbox" :value="item.name">
      </td>           
      <td class="tag">{{item.name}}</td>           
  </tr>
  </table>
```

Comment: И так `:value="item.name" ` и так `:value="{name: item.name}" ` и c этой конструкцией {{}} - не работает(

Comment: @Vlad Сделал сниппет, у меня работает..

Comment: Ой, спасибо Вам большое! Часа два мучаюсь)) Ваш первый вариант сразу заработал, это я тупанул с вебпаком немного.

Comment: @Vlad а подробней можно? Что именно вызвало баг? Я просто тоже webpack использую, интересно на что можно напороться

Comment: Я тут уже задавал вопрос, как фронтенд и бэкэнд vue + node в одном проекте совместить - мне никто не ответил. Ну я сам нашёл простенький бойлерплейт у чувака https://github.com/afterburn/node-vue чтобы легче разобраться было, сделал на его основе свой. Так вот, вебпак с текущими настройками вроде всё релоадит, модули обновляет без релоада и стили инжектит. Как оказалось всё, кроме изменений v-bind. Для них вручную обновить страницу пришлось - тогда всё начало рендерится. А то подставлялось мне `value="item.name"`. Привык, что всё обновляется само, а тут такой подвох.

Comment: Скорее всего у меня руки кривые)) Я только учусь